# AppBarLayout enterAlways to bring back TabLayout and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This is the usual AppBarLayout inside CoordinatorLayout structure, with nested CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout. If you try it you will see that it is work per normal, I suppose. But what I want is for both the ToolBar and the TabLayout to show when the user starts scrolling up. Right now, only the TabLayout shows.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hdrTV"
                style="@style/Header"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:text="@string/geek_viewpoint"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_collapseMode="none"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: maybe remove `enterAlwaysCollapsed` from `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s `layout_scrollFlags`?

Comment: No, that's not it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually your intentions are problematic. If you put your `Toolbar` in clearly collapsing `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and scroll up it is thought to be collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I find my problem. My TabLayout is missing

```
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```